# To know whether selected location is airport or not from google api

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using google's autocomplete feature. I would like to know whether selected location is airport or not. Which google api should I use,  to know whether the fetched location is airport or not. Currently I am using 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London&sensor=true' but these gives types info like country, political, locality, administrative_area_level_2. I want to have info whether the location is airport or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Google Place API and with it, you could find only airports.

The documentation here : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=fr

Does it help you ? Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you're using Google's autocomplete feature, you can ask for the search address' **types** in your `Autocomplete` object, in the `fields` array:

```js
const placeAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($input, {
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' },

    // Depending on what you want from Google Autocomplete request response,
    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/
    // places-service#PlaceResult is the complete list.
    fields: ['place_id', 'name', 'types', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']
});

placeAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    console.log(placeAutocomplete.getPlace());
});
```

So when I search for "pdx" for example and select "Portland International Airport (PDX)", I get "airport" is listed as one of its types:
[image]

Just for comparison, for a random home address, it would show a different type:
[image]

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult lists out all the supported fields you can ask for.